# What ffmpeg command would convert a video for iPad/iPhone in 2021?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp4, ios, quicktime

One of the answers almost a year ago was to use the following command:

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -preset medium -crf 23 -x264-params ref=4 -acodec copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4

That command runs, converts the video but I am unable to hear audio on the pc I converted it on let alone an ios device.

The source file is a home video recorded using the default video settings on an iPhone SE 2020 version, latest version of ios.  I simply attached a usb cable to a PC running Windows 10 with ffmpeg version ffmpeg-2021-02-02-git-2367affc2c-full_build.

The following command allows video and sound to be heard on pc and video on the ios device but no sound:
ffmpeg -i my-video.mov -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 my-video.mp4

Any ffmpeg foo magic warriors out there?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have iOS, but I presume it plays mp3 so you could do someting like this

```
 ffmpeg -i my-video.mov -vcodec h264 -ar 44100 -ac 2 -ab 192k -f mp3 my-video.mp4
```

if not m4a should play for sure so you could use

```
ffmpeg -i my-video.mov -vcodec h264 -c:a aac my-video.mp4
```

Try it out